# String to Double Trouble Shooting

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, double

How do I correctly convert a NSString to a double in xcode 3.2? This is my code(abbreviated), but when I run it, the message says (null). What am I doing wrong?        Thanks so much!

```
@synthesize class1sem1;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed
{   
NSString *myString = class1sem1.text;
double myDouble = [myString doubleValue];


NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                     @"%@", myDouble];

UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Great!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
[message release];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use %g for your double .. not %@

```
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                 @"%g", myDouble];
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to display a double as if it were an object. Use this instead:

```
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                      @"%f", myDouble];
                     //  ^ note 'f' instead of '@'
```

`f` means "double precision floating point number", while `@` means "Objective-C object". A `double` is a double precision floating point number, not an Objective-C object.